# MySQL Trigger on update not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `update`$$
CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `update` AFTER UPDATE
ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `users2` SET `users2`.`username` = new.username AND `users2`.`password` = new.password WHERE `users2`.`id` = new.id;
END;
$$
```

It doesn't generate any errors and not doing it's job either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement is incorrect.

Change it from

```
UPDATE `users2` SET `users2`.`username` = new.username AND `users2`.`password` = new.password WHERE `users2`.`id` = new.id;
                                                       ^^^
```

to

```
UPDATE `users2`       
   SET `username` = new.username, `password` = new.password 
 WHERE `users2`.`id` = new.id;
```